# Ejabberd send message from hooks

Tags: erlang, hook, ejabberd

I have hook handler in my code:

```
ejabberd_hooks:add(sm_register_connection_hook, "localhost", ?MODULE, on_register, 80),

on_register(SID, JID, INFO) ->
    {_, _, _, _, Name, _, _} = JID,
    ok.
```

For example i want to send this Name to gen_server, how can i send message to gen_server for example from this hook with Name? How can i know gen_server's pid inside on_register?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The on_register is a basic module function of ?MODULE. If the gen_server is a singleton server, you can send the name to it using gen_server:call(?MODULE, {name, Name}) or gen_server:cast(?MODULE, {name, Name}).

So the result would look like:

```
on_register(SID, JID, INFO) ->
    {_, _, _, _, Name, _, _} = JID,
    gen_server:call(?MODULE, {name, Name}),
    ok.
```